# jQuery to login as soon as right code is written

Tags: jquery, authentication

I wanna make a page where the are some images, but i only want some to see the images, so when the page first is loaded all it should show is a input field where you can write a passcode, and if it is correct then the field should disappear and the images should show. But i dont want to have to push a button, just as soon as the right password is written the images should reveal themselves. How can i do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/V3UFe/

```
$('#passcode').keyup(function(e){
    if ($(this).val() == "password") {
        $('.hidden-images').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

If you want it to be somewhat secure, you have to do the test for the right passphrase on the server.

Comment: Why the "e" as a parameter to the function?

Comment: That's jQuery convention and represents event data. You don't need it in this case, but it's often useful.

Answer (score 0):

To expand from @LindleyW's answer:

You have 2 ways to check a password:

1. Check password by query your server using AJAX
2. Check password using javascript only

You have stated you don't want to use AJAX, but here it is anyway:

```
$('#your-input-id').on('input', function() {
    var passcode = $(this).val();
    // Use post for more security, i.e. sniffer cannot just look at query string to get passcode
    $.post('/url/to/passcode/checker/script', {passcode: passcode}, function(data) {
        if (data.valid) {
            // show your image here
        }
    });
});
```

You will need a script that checks if the passcode is valid, then return a json response (e.g. `{"valid":true}`), remember to have `content-type` set to `application/json` for jquery's datatype detection to work properly.

Now, if you don't want to check from server... you have 2 ways to do this:

1. Securely (to an extent), by hashing the string and then compare the hash of user input to.
2. Less securely (as in anyone who knows how to look at the web page's source code will be able to figure it out), by simply storing the string as a variable.

**Secure method:**

```
var passcode_hash = 'hashofyourpasscode';
$('#your-input-id').on('input', function() {
    // You have to define hash_function() somewhere, there are plenty of resources out on the internet for such a function
    if (has_function($(this).val()) == passcode_hash) {
        // show image here
    }
});
```

**less secure method**

```
var passcode = 'passcode';
$('#your-input-id').on('input', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == passcode) {
        // show image here
    }
});
```

And as a footnote: It doesn't seem like you did much research at all.